# Python PIL filter drawings

Tags: python, filter, python-imaging-library, paste, transparent

i would like to put lets say a draw.line on some cicles ([see pic below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNyfP.png)) in the same image using python PIL. now i want to filter only the draw.line using ImageFilter.GaussianBlur.

I tried to save the drawings in two diffrent images (image1 and image2) and only blur image1 and then paste them over each other with Image.Image.paste(image2,image1). This works but i do not have transparent background. So it does not look to well.

is there another way i can approch this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please try to improve your question. It is quite difficult to understand what you want and what the issues are. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.